# Implicit conversion from void to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, class, properties

Probably a stupid question, but I'm quite new to the whole "get-and-set-property"-kind of programming;

I keep getting a compiling-error on this part of my code;

```
private string _File = "Session.xml";

private XmlDocument XmlDoc
{
    get
    {
        XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
        return _Doc.LoadXml(_File);
    }
}

private XmlElement XmlRoot
{
    get
    {
        return XmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    }
}
```

How come? I can't explain that to myself as I don't even see any implicit conversions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is your problem:

```
return _Doc.LoadXml(_File);
```

The `LoadXml` method has a return type of `void`, as the method does not return any value, instead populating the `XmlDocument` instance from the file path specified.

To fix your problem, simply change your property to this:

```
private XmlDocument XmlDoc
{
    get
    {
        XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
        _Doc.LoadXml(_File);
        return _Doc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
return _Doc.LoadXml(_File);
```

You're trying to return a value from a method that has a return type of `void`.

Try this instead:

```
private XmlDocument XmlDoc
{
    get
    {
        XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
        _Doc.LoadXml(_File);
        return _Doc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

_Doc.LoadXml(_File); return void and not XmlDocument. Change your code to:

```
private XmlDocument XmlDoc
{
    get
    {
        XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
        _Doc.LoadXml(_File);
        return _Doc;
    }
}
```